# Integration of a function with while loop in R

Tags: r, while-loop, integration

I want to integrate a function involving while loop in R. I have pasted here an MWE. Could anyone please guide about how to get rid of warning messages when integrating such a function?

Thank You

```
myfun <- function(X, a, b, kmin, kmax){
  term <- 0
  k <- 1
  while(k < kmax | term < 10000){
    term <- term + a * b * X^k
    k <- k+1
  }
  fx <- exp(X) * term
  return(fx)
}

a <- 5
b <- 4
kmax <- 20
integrate(myfun, lower = 0, upper = 10, a = a, b = b, kmax = kmax)
```

Produces a warning, accessed via `warnings()`:

```
In while (k < kmax | term < 10000) { ... :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help. Notable is that code fences are three backticks (`\`\`\``), not three single-quotes (`'''`).

Answer (score 3):

From the `integrate()` documentation:

> `f` must accept a vector of inputs and produce a vector of function evaluations at those points.

This is the crux of the problem here, which you can see by running `myfun(c(1, 2), a, b, kmin, kmax)` and reproducing a similar warning. What's happening is that `integrate()` wants to pass a vector of inputs to `myfun` in `X`; this means that inside your `while` loop, `term` will become a vector as well. This creates a problem when the `while` loop kicks back to the evaluation stage, because now the condition `k < kmax | term < 10000` has a vector structure as well (since `term` does), which `while` doesn't like.

This warning is very good in this case, because it strongly suggests that `integrate()` isn't doing what you want it to do. Your goal here isn't to get rid of the warning messages; the function as written simply won't work with `integrate()` due to the `while` loop structure.

Your choices for how to proceed are to either (1) rewrite the function in a way that doesn't use a `while` loop, or (2) just hard-code some numeric integration yourself, perhaps with a `for` loop. The best way to use R is to vectorize everything and to avoid things like `while` and `for` when at all possible.

Finally, I'll note that there seems to be some problem with the underlying function, since `myfun(0.5, a, b, kmin, kmax)` does not converge (note the problem with the mathematics when the supplied X term is less than 1), so you won't be able to integrate it on the interval [0, 10] no matter what you do.

Comment: Dear Aaron. You are absolutely right. Could you please what could be alternative to while loop?

Comment: We could probably rewrite that function without using a while loop, but before we do: is the function really what you intended? Like I mentioned before, having X<1 will ensure that term often converges to some number less than 10000, so the while condition will always be satisfied and the loop will never terminate. Did you perhaps intend for the or operator inside the while argument to be an and operator? Or something else? The function seems fundamentally broken as written, at least if its domain is to include numbers to the left of 1.